# I'm writing a code in Java to check if a string is a palindrome or not. However, the code breaks when spaces are involved

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String original, reverse = "";
    original = scnr.nextLine();

    int length = original.length();

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
    }

    if (original.equals(reverse)){
      System.out.println("palindrome: " + original);
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("not a palindrome: " + original);
    }
   }
}
```

I need to be able to consider strings that are more than 1 word that use spaces. I'm not sure about how to first disregard the location of spaces, and then add them back in, in the correct location to properly test if the phrase is a palindrome.

Comment: You can just remove all the spaces in advance. I don't see why you would try and add them back in.

Comment: Can you give us an example of input with spaces?

Comment: If you are concerned with being able to print the original in your output but not consider it when evaluating if the word/phrase is a palindrome, just make a spaceless copy of it for evaluation and keep the original for your output.

Comment: you can call `trim()` at `scnr.nextLine().trim()`; If you don't care about original input. Or if you do, you can make a copy of it and call `trim()` on that copy and process the copy.

Comment: @KunLun `trim()` only removes space at the start and end of the string, not space between words.

Comment: @FireStar629 please add an example of a String you are having an issue with.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have very specific needs you can use a `StringBuilder` to reverse Strings, no need to handle it manually..

```
public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String original = scnr.nextLine(); 
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(original);
        String reverse = sb.reverse().toString();

        if (original.equals(reverse)){
            System.out.println("palindrome: " + original);
        }else{
            System.out.println("not a palindrome: " + original);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be addressing their question about handling spaces.

Comment: How this can solve his problem with spaces?

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't get to that part - question is closed.